# Problema de Python. Intercalar palabras

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente programa:

> Escriba una función que reciba dos strings como parámetros y retorne
>   un nuevo string que consista del primero, pero con el segundo string
>   intercalado entre cada letra del primero.

**Por ejemplo si los strings son "paz" y "so", entonces tu función debe retornar "psoasozso"**

Mi código:

```
def intercalar(string_a,string_b):

    r = " "
    i= 0
    l=len(string_a)

    while i < l:
        print(string_a[i] + string_b),\

        i = i + 1

    return r

#variables

a=raw_input("Ingrese palabara a: ")
b=raw_input("Ingrese palabara b: ")

variables=intercalar(a,b)

print(variables)
```

Para las palabras: a= paz y b=os me devuelve: pso aso zso

Si uso `print(string_a[i] + string_b),end = ''`, Me da error.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 2):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
def intercalar(a, b):
    i = 0
    cadena = ""
    while(i < len(a)):
        # en lugar de estar imprimiendo dentro del bucle
        # vas a guardar en una variable la nueva cadena en la 
        # cual se soluciona el ejercicio
        cadena += a[i] + b
        # cadena toma lo que ya tenga almacenado (+=) y guarda una letra
        # de la cadena a (a[i]) mas la segunda cadena es decir cadena b
        i = i + 1
    return cadena

# recuerda que en python 3 raw_input paso a ser input
a = raw_input("Ingrese palabara a: ") 
b = raw_input("Ingrese palabara b: ")

print(intercalar(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de AR4Z es correcta y resuelve tu pregunta, pero quiero profundizar en los problemas que tiene tu código. Conceptualmente la idea es correcta pero no llegaste a completarla, veamos que te faltó:

- Defines una variable `r` que es la variable que retornará la función, pero más allá de inicializarla con un espacio, no haces más nada. En principio deberías inicializarla en blanco `r = ""` y luego deberías ir completándola dentro del `while` de esta forma: `r = r + string_a[i] + string_b`.
- Usas un `print` para imprimir cada iteración, pero el `print` es solo eso, una forma de imprimir por consola, que en el caso. En **Python 2x**, el `print valor,` quita el salto de linea pero deja un espacio en blanco y la sintaxis que comentas que en realidad es `print(string_a[i] + string_b,end = '')` es válida solamente en **Python 3x**

Rescribiendo tu código teniendo en cuenta estos detalles:

```
def intercalar(string_a,string_b):

    r = ""
    i= 0
    l=len(string_a)

    while i < l:
        r = r + string_a[i] + string_b
        i = i + 1

    return r
```

Con esto, ahora sí puedes hacer `print(intercalar(a, b))`, el print en este caso será del valor retornado por la función.

Answer (score 2):

Y la críptica solución funcional de una sola línea, que no podía faltar y que dejo aquí para los fans de este tipo de programación (que no para el usuario, a quien posiblemente no le admitan este tipo de respuesta):

```
>>> a = "paz"
>>> b = "so"
>>> "".join("".join(p) for p in zip(a,[b]*len(a)))
'psoasozso'
```

Answer (score 0):

El end = ' ' va dentro del paréntesis. Intenta con este código:

```
def intercalar(string_a, string_b):

    r = " "
    i = 0
    l = len(string_a)

    while i < l:
        print(string_a[i] + string_b, end = '')
        i = i + 1
    return r

a = input("Ingrese palabra a: ") 
b = input("Ingrese palabra b: ")

variables = intercalar(a, b)

print(variables)
```

Otra forma de hacerlo, es sin pedir al usuario que ingrese las palabras por teclado:

```
def intercalar(string_a, string_b):

    r = " "
    i = 0
    l = len(string_a)

    while i < l:
        print(string_a[i] + string_b, end = '')
        i = i + 1
    return r

print(intercalar("paz", "os"))
```